# Strange issue in query parameter

Tags: java, string, jersey, jax-rs, query-string

I am facing strange issue in query parameter. below is my URI

```
http://localhost:8080/aajaxrs-training/api/dynamicEntity/hello?updateMode=FULL&entityName=null
```

so last query parameter user can either put it null or skip it. if it is not present my program will automatically handle it as null. so if I make it absent it runs proper but if I assign the value `null` it doesn't enter the block where I have put condition equals to null.

I think it is considering "`null`" instead if `null`. how to resolve this.
if i assign `@DefaultValue("null")` then it also take it as String instead of absence of value.

```
@GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/{dynamicEntityName}")
    public Response sayHello(@PathParam("dynamicEntityName") String 
    dynamicEntityName,@QueryParam("updateMode") String p_update_mode, 
             @QueryParam("entityName") String p_entity_name) throws Exception
    {

       EntityDataRows readSkill = ODADynamicEntityNEW.getDynamicEntities(p_update_mode, p_entity_name);
        return Response.ok(readSkill).build();
    }
```

I have to handle this parameter `p_entity_name` . if value is not given default value should be null. user can also pass null or any other value.

Comment: If you pass null it will take as null, instead you don't have to pass anything.

Comment: it is taking "null". considering as string

Comment: definitely  : entityName=null will be reading as "null" if you pass entityName=EntityName

it will be as EntityName, either you can do a check in endpoint if 
`entityName=  entityName=="null" ? null : entityName;`